Cache InputStream for annotated methods
I want to cache the input stream of certain endpoints,
have been able to achieve this only for all endpoints.

tried creating an interceptor that turns on caching per method annotation


this fails because the interceptor can't effect the request AFAIK


tried recognizing the handler annotation dynamically in the filter


this fails because the filter load time is before the handler and that data is null.

Basically what I want to ask is, is there a way to add an annotation to a controller method that would cache it's request payload without affecting preexisting endpoints on the same base route?

Solved

created a request that has a cache() medhod
the filter wrappes all requests in cachableRequest
an interceptor runs the cache() method when annotation is present.

:)
